# Security patch supee-8788 - Can it be applied to Magento 2.0.6 community edition?

Tags: magento2, security, patches, supee-8788

**I would like to know if the supee-8788 security patch can be applied to magento 2.0.6** as I am unable to find any documentation on it relating to magento 2.0.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

**SUPEE patches are only relevant to Magento 1.x versions.**

[image]

Thus, you don't need to apply SUPEE-8788 to Magento 2.x

Comment: Hi Thanks..That would make sense.. is there any evidence you can point me to thats says suppee patches are only for magento 1.x versions?

Comment: @Jiyaad.D see the title of the screenshot I posted from the official download page

Answer (score 1):

SUPEE-8788 is only applicable for **Magento 1.x,** so its not possible to apply **SUPEE-8788 to Magento 2.x.**